# Unwanted control characters displaying in vimscript function output

Tags: vim

[using MacVim 7.3 on OS X Lion]

I have a vimscript function which runs an external command.  It's executing correctly, but the output displays (unwanted) control characters, such as `[0m`, `[33m`, `[36m`, and `-1H`.  The relevant line in the vimscript function is:

```
exec ":!bundle exec rspec --color " . a:filename
```

Which produces:

```
:!bundle exec rspec --color spec/acceptance/user_logs_in.feature
[33m*[0m

Pending:
[33m  User logs in [0m
[36m    # the step 'the user "foo@test.host" exists' is not implemented[0m
[36m    # [0m

Finished in 0.07121 seconds
[33m1 example, 0 failures, 1 pending[0m
```

Here's what the same command and output look like from the terminal, which is how I want it to display in vim:

```
$ bundle exec rspec --color spec/acceptance/user_logs_in.feature
*

Pending:
  User logs in
    # the step 'the user "foo@test.host" exists' is not implemented
    #

Finished in 0.1161 seconds
1 example, 0 failures, 1 pending
```

Also, any time I execute and external command, vim displays `-1H` immediately after it.  For example, if I type:

```
:ls<return>
```

I see:

```
:ls-1H
<rest of the output is as expected>
```

Any ideas on hiding those control characters and `-1H`.

(disclaimer: I'm very new to vim so please don't assume too much background knowledge on my part.)

Thanks.

**Update 3/31/2012 @ 17:32 PM**

[Sam Goldman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117607/sam-goldman)'s correct: MacVim doesn't know how to display colors, so it outputs the color codes.

I've switched to terminal vim (which supports colors, at least with [iTerm](http://www.iterm2.com/)), but using the version of vim that comes with MacVim, which is more up-to-date and is compiled with ruby support (among other things). The easiest way to do that is:

```
brew install macvim --override-system-vim
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MacVim doesn't know how to display colors. Terminal vim will display the colors correctly, or you can add --no-color to your rspec command (or a .rspec file). I'm not sure about the -1H thing. Maybe some customization you have for your terminal?